# Does the order of sequential percentage changes matter?

Tags: percentages

Say I have a price that undergoes some fluctuations, measure in percentage.

Example: Item A costs \$100, and the price is increased by $4.5\%$ four times, and then decreased by $4.5\%$ four times, in that order.

The way I see it, this just means that the final price $F = \$100 \cdot 1.045^4 \cdot 0.955^4$, but since multiplication is commutative, the order of these fluctuations doesn't matter.

Does that mean that we can just consider the *set* of eight changes, and disregard the order in which they are applied to the price?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Unless it matters when (or in what order) the price is higher or lower.  But the ending price will be the same in any case.